# Cron runs every 2 mins but when scheduled to run on a specific hour it doesn't work

Tags: linux, cron

When I put a cronjob like this it works.

```
*/2 * * * * /opt/reports/ussd_tps.sh
```

But I put it like this, it doesn't work.

```
35 01 * * * /opt/reports/ussd_tps.sh
```

Comment: What do you think that 35 01 line should do? (What time do you think it should it run?) How are you sure it's not working?

Comment: It's unclear what exactly "doesn't work" means. Does the job not run at 01:35 in the morning?

Comment: It **does** work... but your  fury may be obscuring your vision?

Comment: I've check this all day, I scheduled it to run on various hours and it didn't work that's why I posted it here, if my fury is obscuring my vision I'd go to a witch doctor. Cron doesn't run when I schedule it in an hourly manner.

Comment: Why do you put '0' in front of '1' in hour definition? In `man 5 crontab` when there's *1* in cron job definition it is always *1* and not *01*? And you can run `cron` in foreground and debug to see what's going on... `cron -in -x ext,sch,proc,pars,load,misc,test,bit` (cronie version of cron used here).

Comment: @JiriB the leading zero doesn't make any difference (to me). Sometimes it's convenient - particularly if you have several jobs and you want to line up the columns